# Update variable angular

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in Angular, and I have a problem:

I have an array, with edit button. This button, edit customer on modal

I send parameter on my method for open modal for recover good information on this.

But i do this:

```
$scope.dataEdit = param;
```

i try to `console.log $scope.dataEdit` and i have good information

but after how i can send it on my modal ?

```
<h4 class="modal-title">{{{dataEdit}}</h4>
```

I do this, but i have nothing, i use other variable and i can display it, but why my variable does not update?

My Controller :

```
Customer.controller('Customer', function ($scope, apiREST, $uibModal) {
$scope.test = 10;
$scope.dataModalEdit = [];



$scope.open = function (view, param) {
    switch (view) {
        case 'edit':
            var templateUrl = 'edit.view.html';
            var controller = 'Customer';
            break;
    }

    $scope.dataModalEdit = param;

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: templateUrl,
        controller: controller,
        size: '',
        backdrop  : true,
        keyboard  : false,
        resolve: {
            items: function() {
                return {
                   param
                };
            }
        }
    });
};
$scope.action();
```

});

```
 my view 
 
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{dataModalEdit.name}}</h4> // empty <h4
 class="modal-title">{{test}}</h4> // 10
```

Ty

Comment: Please post all relevant code, what is the method for opening the modal? What's the HTML look like?

Comment: Also.. is this angularjs or angular..???

Comment: i update my post

its angular js

Comment: `angular` !== `angularjs`. `angular` is for v2+, based on the use of `$scope` and the fact that you're "getting good information" denotes this is AngularJS.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

Comment: @Phix, did you have idea ?

Answer (score 0):

To help you to understand the content of your var, you can add in the view:

```
 {{dataModalEdit  | json  }}
```

How do you call `$scope.open()` ?
If it is not called from an Angular event, you should add in your function

```
        $scope.dataModalEdit = param;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
```

after the data change, to force Angular to update the view.